# Retrieving today date data from mysql using pdo

Tags: php, pdo

I have some data in my table which are `[name][address][phone_number]` and the date in this format `2015-10-14 14:37:38`. I am using php PDO. How can I query out just today date from the table?

The following code is my code to query out result for the past 7 days which worked perfectly. However, whenever I replace it with 1 it doesn't work:

```
$query = $digital->query('SELECT * FROM sales WHERE `datetime` BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 7 DAY) AND NOW() ORDER BY sale_id DESC');
```

What I want is to be able to query out all today data inserted into database.

Comment: you can help instead of down voting it.

Comment: What do you actually want to achieve? Please mention correct db structure, your requirement and what you have tried on your own.

Comment: what i want to achieve is to show only data with the current date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this, haven't tested.

```
<?php
$todaysDate = date('Y-m-d'); //if your date is stored in y-m-d format
        try
        {
            $s = $conn->query("SELECT * from sales where datetime LIKE '%$todaysDate%'");
        }
        catch(PDOException $e)
        {
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }
        $results = $s->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

?>
```

Your query results is now in `$results` variable.

Extended version

```
    <?php
try
        {
            $s = $conn->query("SELECT * from sales");
        }
        catch(PDOException $e)
        {
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }

    while($results = $s->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ))
    {
        $date = explode(" ", $results->datetime);
        if($date[0] == date('Y-m-d'))
        {
            //write code here to display data
        }
    }

?>
```

Make sure you replace all the columnNames and tablename.
Edit :-
Here's a sqlfiddle pertaining to my first solution. 
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7c2f1/3

Comment: the above code work no error but its showing no result

Comment: @SegunOyebode Post your db structure.

Comment: the column are sale_id| name | quantity | unit_prize | total_prize | datetime

Comment: @SegunOyebode You did not mention your tablename buddy.

Comment: sorry table name is sales

Comment: Just updated my code with correct tablename and columnName.

Comment: that was how i put it initially that it print out black page

Comment: $todaysDate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s'); //if your date is stored in y-m-d format
       try
    {
        $s = $digital->query("SELECT * from sales");
    }
    catch(PDOException $e)
    {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }

while($results = $s->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ))
{
    $date = explode(" ", $results->datetime);
    if($date[0] == date('Y-m-d H:i:s'))
    {
       echo $results['name'] ; //write code here to display data
    }else{
  echo 'no result found';
  }
}

Comment: @SegunOyebode
Updated my answer, also included an SQL Fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know whether it applies to PDO, as I'm not very acquainted to it, but I use to pass the date in a var, then ask for a match in my sql statement

```
// choose your own timezone here
date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo');
// then define your variable as the current time:
$date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
```

then, i'd use the correct PDO syntax to compare the column with the var (a simple "where" statement should do it).

(using codeigniter syntax)

$this->db->where('date', $date);